# Custom validation rule in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to create a custom validation rule for when a checkbox is checked, an input field will need to be filled out in order to proceed to the next page.  If unchecked, the input field will not be required.

Here's my code in View:

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend'=>'Certifications',
    'rn_box'=>array(
        'type'=>'checkbox',
        'label'=>'RN',
        'value' => $results['Education']['rn_box']
        ),
    'rn_number'=>array(
        'label'=>'RN Number:',
        'value' => $results['Education']['rn_number']
        ),
```

));

In my Model I created a function:

```
public function rnCheck () {
if ($this->data['Education']['rn_box'] == '0') {
    return false;
}
    return true;
```

}

```
public $validate = array(
    'rn_number' => array(
        'rnCheck'=>array(
            'rule'=>'rnCheck',
            'message'=>'Please Provide a Number'
            ),
        ),
```

);

The checkbox returns a value of 1 if checked, and a value of 0 unchecked.  The rn_number field is an input field that I'm trying to validate.  I tried playing with 'required', 'allowEmpty', etc. with no luck.  If anyone can point me in the right direct, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just handle it all in the function callback for rn_number. I would also call the function and rule name rn_number to avoid any confusion.

For example, change your validate array to:

```
public $validate = array(
    'rn_number' => array(
        'rn_number'=>array(
            'rule'=>'rn_number'
        ),
    ),
);
```

And then your custom validation function can look like:

```
public function rn_number () {
    if ($this->data['Education']['rn_box'] == 1) {
            if($this->data['Education']['rn_number'] == '')
                  $errors[] = "Please enter your RN Number.";
    }

    if (!empty($errors))
        return implode("\n", $errors);

    return true;
}
```

I'm handling the error message in the custom validation function - not in the validate array. Let me know if this doesn't work!